# Confirming the nature of a Samsung update, and declining it

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, kernel

I find it a little bit offensive to receive a "Software Update" message on my Galaxy Note 2 that does not disclose the nature of the update (an OS update? an app update?).

[image: software update message]
<sup>software update message (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Judging by the timing, the chatter, and especially the size, I am guessing Samsung is pushing a 4.4 (KitKat) update, but given the lousy experience of reduced battery performance after upgrading from 4.1 to 4.3 (including giving a chance for recalibration with many full discharge/recharge cycles), I'd rather avoid 4.4 for now.

My question is in two parts:

1. How do I confirm that this is indeed KitKat being pushed?
2. How do I decline the update, or at least delay it by longer than three hours?

[image: 3 hour max delay]
<sup>3 hour max delay (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Go to SamMobile and navigate to the check your firmware and you can see what your carrier is pushing.

Comment: I am happy to report that upgrading from 4.3 to 4.4.2 made the battery last three days instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first part-** Samsung has notes on the system updates on their site. I'm not sure what provider you're using, but you should be able to get to what you're looking for if you start at: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/

Use the "Start by Entering..." search bar in the middle of the screen to pull up your specific Note II phone and scroll down to the "Support Overview" section.

For the model I looked up, the "*Which version of the Android™ platform does my Samsung Note II use?*" question is already in the Frequently Asked Questions list, but if not, use the search bar just about that.

I didn't check every device, but it certainly looks like it's the Kit Kat update that's been downloaded.

**For the second part-** I'm working off the assumption that your Note is NOT rooted. Upfront note (haha): I don't have a Note II here with me, so I'm going off reference materials and memory on the exact option names in the menus. These steps should let you disable the notification until you re-enable automatic updates.

1. Go to 'Settings'
2. Click 'More'
3. Click 'About device'
4. Click 'Software update'
5. Uncheck the 'Auto update – Check for updates automatically' option

When the update prompt is in your notifications, pull down the notification list and do the following:

1. Press and hold down on the update until you get a 'App Info' option
2. Click 'App Info'
3. Click 'Clear cache'
4. Click 'Clear data'